# Input string error

Tags: c#, asp.net

Following is code:

```
 string checkuser = "select * from [User] where UserName='" + txtusername.Text + "'";
 SqlCommand com = new SqlCommand(checkuser, con);
 int temp = Convert.ToInt32(com.ExecuteScalar().ToString());
 con.Close();
 if (temp == 1)
```

Problem:

whenever i run following code it gives error that **Input string was not in a correct format**.

Comment: It will be erroing on the Convert to int. This command will return all of the text in all of the fields. You are then trying to convert all of this text to an integer that will fail. You could change the SQL query to use "select count(*) from..." instead and this should then work.

Comment: What are you intending to store in 'temp'?

Answer (score 3):

try with

```
string checkuser = "select count(*) from [User] where UserName=@UserName";
```

your problem is `ExecuteScalar` return the first row , first column value of the result and it can't convert to a integer

if you have number column , for example `age`, do as below

```
string checkuser = "select age from [User] where UserName=@UserName";
```

your SQL statement widely open for sql injection attacks, you better use parameters

```
string sql= "select count(*) from [User] where UserName = @UserName";
using(SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(conString))
using(SqlCommand cmd= new SqlCommand(sql, con))
{
   con.Open();
   cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@UserName", txtusername.Text);
   int temp = Convert.ToInt32(cmd.ExecuteScalar().ToString());
   if(temp == 1)
   {}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

[`ExecuteScalar`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.executescalar%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) returns first column of the first row the result of your query. And looks like your `com.ExecuteScalar().ToString()` is not a valid integer, that's why you get this error.

If you want to count your query, you need to use `SELECT COUNT(*)` instead of `SELECT *`

And please use [parameterized queries](http://blog.codinghorror.com/give-me-parameterized-sql-or-give-me-death/). This kind of string concatenations are open for [SQL Injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection) attacks.

Also use [`using` statement](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yh598w02.aspx) to dispose your `SqlConnection` and `SqlCommand` like;

```
using(SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(strConnString))
using(SqlCommand com = con.CreateCommand())
{
   string checkuser = "select COUNT(*) from [User] where UserName = @user";
   com.CommandText = checkuser;
   com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@user", txtusername.Text);
   int temp = (int)com.ExecuteScalar();
   if(temp == 1)
   ///
}
```

Also you can use `ExecuteScalar` for getting first row of the specific column value with specifiying column in your query like `SELECT columnname from [User]...`

Answer (score 0):

You should return **a scalar value**. But, in your query you are returning a `result set` which is not **compatible** with `String` type.

**So, modify your query as follows:**

```
string checkuser = "select count(*) from [User] where UserName='" + txtusername.Text + "'";
```

The above returns only a `single value` that can fit into string.